# Using Twitter advanced search to find users that match certain criteria

Tags: twitter, search

Is it possible to use Twitter's advanced search function (or something else) to find people that tweet about a certain topic regularly, or that match a certain criteria?

For example, I'm looking for people who play **soccer-baseball** (also known as kickball) in my area and have a lot of followers (lets say over 5000).

The only thing I can think of is to perform an [advanced twitter search](http://search.twitter.com/search?q=&ands=&phrase=soccer+baseball&ors=&nots=&tag=&lang=all&from=&to=&ref=&near=toronto&within=500&units=km&since=&until=&rpp=50), and then "study" the search results for profiles that meet my criteria.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

You can try the "who to follow" feature in Twitter, which enables you to search by name or topic.
http://twitter.com/#!/who_to_follow/search/kickball

Comment: Feature is gone

Answer (score 0):

[Twellow](http://twellow.com) allows you do this via the following query,
http://twellow.com/search/?q=kickball
Though you are not able to filter by the followers count.

[Wefollow](http://wefollow.com) instead allows you to sort by most followers,
http://wefollow.com/twitter/kickball
You are not able to filter by location.

Comment: Both seem gone? There is crowdfireapp though http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/93159/follow-users-by-criteria-on-twitter