# Follow users by criteria on Twitter

Tags: twitter, search, twitter-api, crowdfire

Keeping in mind Twitter's [Following rules and best practices](https://support.twitter.com/articles/68916), I've tried [Crowdfire's Keyword follow](https://crowdfire.freshdesk.com/support/solutions/articles/5000645781-what-is-keyword-follow-) and I find it very powerful because:

1. I can easily list many users whose profile or tweets match a keyword or hashtag, with a filter by location (e.g. country);
2. I can follow them massively with a simple click, the list shifts to hide followed users so I don't *need* to even move the mouse (or I can [autoclick thousands of times with a certain delay](https://askubuntu.com/questions/179581/how-can-i-make-my-mouse-auto-click-every-5-seconds/179754#comment1144101_329009) and go have lunch);
3. I can easily reduce noise later, by unfollowing the users who didn't follow back etc., because previous follows will be hidden next time (it doesn't look good if you continuously follow and unfollow a user).

However I'd like to narrow down the accounts returned by the search, with some further criteria like:

1. sort by relevance, list first the users who used the keyword most often;
2. filter by user statistics, e.g. min/max number of followers or tweets, difference between followers and following;
3. filter by negative keyword, to exclude those who have some word(s) in their bio (and tweets?).

Search results are seemingly [limited to one week's tweets](https://socialbearing.com/faqs/does-twitter-limit-tweet-display); mass inspection of tweets over a period of months would require analysis of the [twitterstream dumps](https://archive.org/details/twitterstream).

Comment: I'm now looking into SocialBearing (found [via Buffer](https://blog.bufferapp.com/free-twitter-tools)) which uses a [quality score](https://socialbearing.com/blog/twitter-user-quality-score) and has various search features.